# Is it safe to `pip install -r requirements.txt` after upgrading the interpreter?

Tags: python, pip

I've created a virtualenv using Python 3.6 using:

```
> python -m venv venv
> pip install <whatever>
> pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

A few months later, I've upgraded to Python 3.8.

Is it guaranteed that a package/version which works on 3.6, exists and works on 3.8? For sports, what about the other way around (downgraded Python, wanna use old requirements).

Comment: Of course. Why not ? Why just don't you try and see that there is no trouble ? ^^

Comment: new environment, new python, old requirement, it won't explode XD

Comment: @azro tried it. Actually some of the packages failed to install.

Comment: So you know the answer. The readl question now is : how to install the packages that have failed, and for that you may share the errors

Comment: In that case there's no choice but to use another package, tell the developers to fix it, fix it yourself, or create a virtual environment with a different Python version... yes, you figured out yourself that it's not safe.

Comment: @azro I mean, there’s nothing “of course” about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that packages between versions will work. They should due to backwards compatibility in the Python versions and maintainers running good unit testing, but there is always a chance something could break. This is why people use venv's and lock versions on their packages.

To confirm it works, make a new venv with your updated Python version and pip install everything and see if it works. If it breaks, you know that you need to stick with the previous venv until the package issues are resolved by the maintainers.